# Why would you allow a static field exist twice?

Tags: java, static

Here we go with my question:

I have an interface with a **static variable nr**

```
public interface TestInterface {    

    public static int nr = 1;

}
```

And a class which implements that interface and has it's own **static variable nr too**.

```
public class TestClass implements TestInterface {

    public static int nr = 2;

}
```

And I can actually do this **without an error!**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        TestClass test = new TestClass();

        System.out.println(TestClass.nr);

    }`
```

Question: **Why would this be allowed?**

As far as I understand static fields should be universal through a class instances but what about the superclass - subclass relation?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: `superclass - subclass relation` This relationship doesn't exist here, it's just a class implementing an interface.

Comment: Because this is confusing from a "revisiting this code" point of view. By not being possible imposes better practices.

Comment: The Interface variable should be spelled in all upper case by convention, because it's a constant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In superclass - subclass relation the super class's static variables is shadowed by sub class's static variables if they have same name. Because the static variables aren't polymorphic.

Comment: Hidden, not shadowed.

Answer (score 1):

It's explicitly allowed by the language.

> If the class declares a field with a certain name,
>   then the declaration of that field is said to *hide*
>   any and all accessible declarations of fields with
>   the same name in superclasses, and
>   superinterfaces of the class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3

Answer (score 0):

In your code, both of the `static` fields are actually defined/meant for separate types i.e., one for `TestInterface` interface type and other for `TestClass` class type.

One point you need to understand is that, when it comes to `static`, there is no overriding, so they will be treated as separate fields.

Comment: It is incorrect that static fields are not inherited. The JLS mandates, `"A class inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces all the non-private fields of the superclass and superinterfaces that are both accessible to code in the class and not hidden by a declaration in the class."` Static fields are shown in that section's examples.

Comment: @LewBloch What I mean by inheritance is that we can't override, corrected to make it more clear